# Пропали все файлы из папки /bin/Debug

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Во время работы в программе Visual Studio над проектом WinForms пропали все файлы из папки /bin/debug. При попытке создать новый проект для переноса данных со старого проекта папке в bin/Debug вообще не появляется никаких файлов. При запуске проекта выпадает окно: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно сделать?

Comment: Чтобы там что-то появилось, надо сначала собрать проект. Удалите полностью папки bin и obj, и пересоберите проект.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо!